# Is base64 considered encryption in an iPhone app?

Tags: encryption, app-store, base64, appstore-approval

Is simple base64 encoding (for posting binary data to apples validation servers) considered encryption and would I have to report this when uploading my app to the appstore?

Comment: Well, if it is, then Apple would have a hard job arguing that any kind of encoding isn't encryption. I'd say the answer here is an emphatic no, but I might be wrong.

Comment: No it's not ... it's encoded but not encrypted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  and/or the store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that something like base64 would not be considered encryption, because it is a known encoding algorithm, and has nothing to do with encryption.  Base64 encoding is used for lots of different things including encoding things in email.  I don't see how anybody would interpret this as encryption.

But then again, Apple has rejected apps for some pretty weird reasons, so if you can disclose to them clearly that you are using base64 to encode data, then it's probably safer to do so upfront, so you can say they were aware of it all along.

Comment: Unless Apple has rejected an application for using base64 encoding, this is a fairly speculative answer, and therefore of questionable utility. I find it difficult to believe that Apple's developers and testing staff are incapable of distinguishing an encoding regime with one that performs encryption. Were they to make such a mistake, I speculate such behavior would be front page news in most technical forums.

Answer (score 12):

No, base64 encoding is not encryption.

Comment: ** Unless Apple says it is.

Comment: What does that even mean? What a strange comment.

Comment: Not the original poster, but here's my take.  Apple has rejected some apps for some really arguable reasons.   If you are using base64 encoding and apple says that it qualifies as encryption. then it qualifies as encryption.  Most people wouldn't say it is, but I've known some people who used it to obfuscate what was being sent over the network, or stored in files.  Sure it's not real encryption, but it will stop some people.  It will bring the level of reading the text from 1 to 3, whereas real encryption would bring the it up to a level of 100.

Comment: I have never heard of Apple rejecting an application for using Base64 encoding. Sounds like FUD to me.

Answer (score 9):

The main reason Apple cares: compliance with US export laws. Base64 encoding has never been considered an encryption technology by the NIST/Commerce Department.

As others have said, you never know when you're going to get an arbitrary reviewer, but the direct and simple answer is **no**. Source: http://csrc.nist.gov/

Answer (score 7):

base64 is an encoding scheme, not an encryption algorithm.

The distinction is, although neither are particularly human-readable, encoding strives to store or display data in a manner consistent with the media at hand, where encryption is a deliberate attempt to obfuscate the data from all but its intended users.

Answer (score 6):

Apple asks about encryption to see if the application may need authorization for export from the Department of Commerce/Bureau of Industry and Security.

Base64 encoding is not considered encryption; it is considered a 'fixed' coding technique in in accord with the Technical Note to 15 CFR part 774, Supplement 1, ECCN 5A002, paragraph a.1, which explains that "Cryptography" for export purposes does not  include 'fixed' data compression or coding techniques.  The definition of 'fixed' appears at 15 CFR part 772.1.

http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/ccl5pt2.pdf

Also, you can call the Department of Commerce/Bureau of Industry and Security at 202-482-0707 and ask about your specific application.

Comment: Also, DOC/NIST does not regulate encryption exports; the DOC/Bureau of Industry and Security does.